# Moving an object in a direction with opengl java

Tags: java, opengl

I am trying to move a triangle in the direction of the top vertex.

Depending on the rotation angle.

This is my code:

```
private static void render() {
    // Clear the pixels on the screen and clear the contents of the depth buffer (3D contents of the scene)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Reset any translations the camera made last frame update
     glLoadIdentity();
    // Apply the camera position and orientation to the scene
    //camera.applyTranslations();
    glTranslated(0,0,-5);
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotated(f.get_direction(),0,0,1);
    glTranslated(x,y,0);
    f.draw();
    glPopMatrix();
    x+=(f.get_speed()/30)*cos(f.get_direction()+90);
    y+=(f.get_speed()/30)*sin(f.get_direction()+90);
}
```

The point is that no matter what is the rotation angle that is the direction,
i want to move the triangle according to it.

Comment: Please explain what the problem is. And the cos/sin function in java take radians so the +90 looks wrong to me.

Comment: Swap the order of rotation and translation. Since the last specified transformation is applied first, your current code first translates, then rotates. It sounds like you want the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to translate according to direction vector but there is simple problem `cos` and `sin` arguments is in radians `glRotate` in degrees:

so we must create static function

```
static double degToRad(double x)
{
    return (x / 180.0) * Math.PI;
}
```

than use it

```
glLoadIdenity();

x += Math.cos(degToRad(getDirection() + 90)) * getSpeed();
y += Math.sin(degToRad(getDirection() + 90)) * getSpeed();

glTranslatef(x, y, 0);

glRotatef(getDirection(), 0, 0, 1);

drawObject();
```

you can also invert direction of movement just subsctacting current angle from 360:

```
glLoadIdenity();

x += Math.cos(degToRad(360 - getDirection() + 90)) * getSpeed();
y += Math.sin(degToRad(360 - getDirection() + 90)) * getSpeed();

glTranslatef(x, y, 0);

glRotatef(getDirection(), 0, 0, 1);

drawObject();
```

Comment: Yes I tried it but when I call "draw" that draw a triangle the movment not at the  right direction it move in another side

Comment: Is there another way to calculate the new position